# Python Classes Confusion in variable

Tags: python, discord

```
#Classes

class get:
    def channel(channelname):
        """Returns a channel object from the channel name."""
        return utils.get(Guild.text_channels, name=channelname)

    def role(rolename):
        """Returns a role object from the role name."""
        return utils.get(Guild.roles, name=rolename)
```

**error message**:
Method should have "self" as first argument

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: see more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [self](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/) as the first argument of any method of a class:

```
class get:
    def channel(self, channelname):
        """Returns a channel object from the channel name."""
        return utils.get(Guild.text_channels, name=channelname)

    def role(self, rolename):
        """Returns a role object from the role name."""
        return utils.get(Guild.roles, name=rolename)
```

Comment: Except for static methods

Comment: Except for static methods and class methods actually